# Send notification everyday even when the app is closed and get location in background

Tags: android, service, notifications, background, alarmmanager

I am making a weather app where the user will be notified every day, at a certain hour if he needs to get his umbrella outside or not. I did some research and I am using AlarmManager for notifications but I need somehow to always have the current location, or at least get it when I want to fire the notification. I did a lot of research but I still don't get it how to implement and have it as a background service. I was thinking to store lat and long coordinates in shared preferences so I can access them from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

- Fix your time to send notification and set in alarm manager using exact method
- Get lat long (When alarm manager call notification method) while sending notification if GPS is disabled you can simple check for previous lat long value and show that weather or don't send notification
- Use shared preferences to store some values(like lat long) as you need
- Try this free weather api
  https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=35&lon=139